# Expresso Store — multiple shipping addresses?

Tags: expresso-store, plugin, shipping

I know I can use different shipping and billing addresses for an order, which is stored by member purchasing but I wanted to see what was the best way to do the following:

Have one billing address, and be able to store multiple shipping addresses, being able to choose the one I want when I get to the checkout process in this part. A lot like an Amazon-type effort, bill all the time to the same person, ship to different stored addresses.

I am thinking this might be a plugin added to it, or if anyone has already done it, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't believe this is available currently. I would recommend reaching out to Expresso Store folks to ask about some custom dev work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way built into Store that would allow you to do what you want to do out of the box. If you are storing the shipping details as channel entries it would be pretty easy to link the customer to multiple channel entries (by making them the author) and show those on the top of your checkout template. Then when the user has select a specific address you can use the entry_id to output the address into your Store checkout fields.

Comment: How would you go about "making them the author" automatically?

Comment: YOu would want to create a SafeCracker Form on your site to add/edit addresses. Then after the user is logged in they will automatically be the author of the entries they publish. You can use the author_only parameter to prevent other users from editing/seeing the entry. (you will need to make sure that the channel that you store the data in the member group of your site members has posting privileges in that channel)